# Python np select to create a new column by applying condition on other columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, if-statement

I am trying to create a new column for a data frame, but it seems giving incorrect result in the new column, The data is below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,30,size=10),
                 columns=["Random"],
                 index=pd.date_range("20180101", periods=10))
df=df.reset_index()
df.loc[:,'Random'] = '20'
df['Recommandation']=['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No']
df['diff']=[3,2,4,1,6,1,2,2,3,1]
df
```

I am trying to create another column in 'new' by using the following condition:

```
If the 'index' is in the first three date, then, 'new'='random', 
elif the 'Recommendation' is yes, than 'new'= 'Value of the previous row of the new column'+'diff'
else: 'new'= 'Value of the previous row of the new column'
```

My code is below:

```py
import numpy as np
df['new'] = 0
df['new'] = np.select([df['index'].isin(df['index'].iloc[:3]), df['Recommandation'].eq('Yes')],
                     [df['new'], df['diff']+df['new'].shift(1)],
                     df['new'].shift(1)
                     )
#The expected output
df[new]=[20,20,20,21,27,28,28,28,31,31]
df
```

Comment: Your code runs without errors for me...

Comment: @BeRT2me  I edited the question a bit, It rans without error, but it doesn't give what I want in the column 'new'

Comment: Well, showing what it is you 'want' in the column 'new' sounds like an important part to add to your question, add an example of the exact desired input/output, not just parameters~

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python If else multiple condition to apply condition on different columns for creating a new columns is giving syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72679090/python-if-else-multiple-condition-to-apply-condition-on-different-columns-for-cr)

Comment: @BeRT2me No that one is using the other column to replace the value of the new column, but my new column is like: for the date that belongs to 1-3, df[new]=df[random],  but for other months, df[new]=df[previous row value of new]+df[diff]( when recommand is yes) and df[new]=df[random],  but for other dates, df[new]=df[previous row value of new]( when recommand is no)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,30,size=10),
                 columns=["Random"],
                 index=pd.date_range("20180101", periods=10))
df = df.reset_index()
df.loc[:,'Random'] = 20
df['Recommandation'] = ['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No']
df['diff'] = [3,2,4,1,6,1,2,2,3,1]
df.loc[5, 'index'] = pd.to_datetime('2018-01-02')  # I modified this data

df['new'] = df['diff']
df['new'] = df['new'].where(df.Recommandation.eq('Yes'))
# the mask that 'index' is in the first three date
m = df['index'].isin(df['index'][:3])
df.loc[m, 'new'] = df.Random
idx = m[m].index.drop([df.index.min()], errors='ignore')
df['new'] = pd.concat(map(lambda x: x.cumsum().ffill(), np.split(df.new, idx)))
df
>>>
    index     Random    Recommandation  diff    new
0   2018-01-01  20      No              3       20.0
1   2018-01-02  20      Yes             2       20.0
2   2018-01-03  20      No              4       20.0
3   2018-01-04  20      Yes             1       21.0
4   2018-01-05  20      Yes             6       27.0
5   2018-01-02  20      Yes             1       20.0
6   2018-01-07  20      No              2       20.0
7   2018-01-08  20      No              2       20.0
8   2018-01-09  20      Yes             3       23.0
9   2018-01-10  20      No              1       23.0
```

Comment: What if we have more data, where the index is repeating, but other values change. I mean, it's not only for the first three data, it will be for any data that belongs to data 1,2, or 3.

Comment: it works for this sample data, but while doing with the real data, it gives ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: You first need to make sure you don't have duplicate indexes for your data, Or your simulated data is not close to your real data

Comment: I have tried: df = df.drop_duplicates() and 
df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()].copy()       to remove any duplicate rows/column before using pd.concat, but it's having the issue.

Comment: According to the data you provided, I made a simple modification, and the result of my code is correct. If your question is not well described and you can't get the answer you want, you can re-post a post